# Слово "дональд" в значении стикер

Tags: лексика

Когда в 1990-х жевачки с вкладышами стали популярны, у нас в Армении появилось слово "дональд" как название этого вкладыша. Но сегодня обнаружил, что эта языковая реалия не всем известна за пределами Армении. Более того, она отсутствует и в словарях. А вам известна эта реалия? Если нет, то как вы называли  эти вкладаши в то время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была марка жевачки Donald, по имени персонажа мультфильмов об утёнке Дональде (Donald Duck), в неё вкладывались комиксы, которые сейчас даже коллекционируют. Видимо, где-то это слово стало нарицательным для похожей продукции. 
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Disney-Donald-Bubble-Chewing-30pcs/dp/B013PIMR54

Comment: Вы правы, это и послужило названием. Но известно ли это название вам?

Comment: Про утёнка Дональда слышал, не более.

Comment: А как вы называли эти вкладыши?

Comment: Я никогда не покупал жевачки. По форме это "вкладыши", по содержанию - "комиксы". Обертку (сложенную для игры в фантики) дети обычно называют "фантиком".